# Explanation needed for behavior of Executorservice

Tags: java, android, multithreading, executorservice

Please consider the following pseudocode

```
private ExecutorService mPool;

private final static int THREADS = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(); // which is 8 in my case

mPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREADS);

while ( go through a long list of images )
{
     if( !mPool.isShutdown() )
     {
         mPool.execute( new MyRunnable( path of image );
     }
}

....

....


private class MyRunnable implements Runnable
{
    public void run()
    {
         // do something with each image
    }
}
```

I have executed the above with different number of threads. Below are my observations

```
100 threads  => 573 seconds
100 threads  => 584 seconds ( Just tried for a second time with same number of threads )
50 threads   => 574 seconds
10 threads   => 502 seconds
5 threads    => 589 seconds
1 thread     => 695 seconds 
8 threads    => 584 seconds ( Same number of threads as the number of cores in my phone )
4 threads    => 579 seconds
16 threads   => 581 seconds
```

I have the following questions.

1) Why doesn't using 4 threads not increase the time to double as that of when I used 8 threads? I observe the time duration for job completion is almost the same.

2) When I use more than 8 threads, is the OS considering only 8 threads or lesser?

3) Is there a better programmatic approach to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the ExecutorService is executing the Runnable by assigning it to a particular Thread from the threadpool.

Once a thread has completed its execution, the threadpool can reassign a new task to it.
In other words, a task taking 1 hour when run in a single thread may end up taking 40 minutes when running in 2 threads. There is a chance that when I increase the threads, the code will take lesser time, but there may be a chance that even with more threads, at the end of the day, a lot of threads in the pool remain unused.

So it is not necessary that running some tasks with an executor service containing a threadpool of 8 threads will execute at half the time as that of 4 threads.
It would depend on the task that is being assigned.

- I suggest you to check the time taken by this task to run for each individual image once.
  (I see you have a collective data of 1 thread being run in 695 seconds).
- Check the runnable code. Are there any synchronized blocks? That would also affect the speed of execution.

All in all, you need to break down your code and figure out which lines are taking time in execution. Then you can better design your code to be run parallel to each other.

If you share more code of what you are doing and how you are calculating the time of execution exactly, you might get